# Standardized initial margin calculation

Tags: initial-margin

BCBS 261 sets specific rules regarding to the initial margin calculation for bilateral trade (https://www.bis.org/publ/bcbs261.pdf)

In page 21, the standardized rule sets the methodology for the same which is basically

```
Net Margin = (0.40 + 0.60 * NGR) * Gross Margin
```

Where `NGR` is the ratio of Net to gross Market value of the underlying trades in the portfolio.

I could not understand the logic of the formula `(0.40 + 0.60 * NGR)`. I understand that the ratio for net to gross margin is assumed as a function of 60% of the ratio for net to gross market value due to consideration of future exposure. So that signifies 0.60 in above formula. However what is the significance of 0.40?